# Running 2 .py file with a .py file

Tags: javascript, python, file

I need to execute 2 .py files (or even better a .js and a .py) by opening one .py file. How can I do it? I tried with os and subprocess but it works only if I execute it from the console and not by opening it manually.

```
import subprocess
path = r"D:\dir"
tasks = ['main.py', 'bot.py']
task_processes = [
    subprocess.Popen(r'python %s\%s' % (path, task), shell=True)
    for task
    in tasks
]
for task in task_processes:
    task.wait()
```

Comment: do you need to run in parallel or one after another?

Comment: in parallel, consider that they are 2 bots

Comment: I would rather switch to threading module then and run subprocess from a thread

Comment: This is what import does. `import bot.py` will load/run anything in that file.

Comment: LOL. it is not about import but about how you treat parallel run. I would run each tool in subthread instead of doing like you did.

Comment: It does not works with import

Comment: Thanks @BeliaevMaksim. I'm a beginner, I'll try google it and try it, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import threading

def start():
    exec(open("D:\\dir\\main.py","r").read())
    exec(open("D:\\dir\\bot.py","r").read())

threading.Thread(target=start,daemon=1).start()
```

Hope I Help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt, add the error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask